# To pass parameters to Result handler function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making `XMLHttpRequest` to call Google search API URL. And on getting the response I want to call another result Handling function. But I also want to pass the parameter to it.

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();

if(request) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/final_project/SearchService";
    url += "?user_query=" + getQueryString();

    request.onreadystatechange = handleSearchResult;
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

Here `handleSearchResult` is `resultHandler` and I want to pass parameter to this function. But if I do so the function gets called directly.

What can be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround it using a closure:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  handleSearchResult(yourParameter);
}
```